# NestJS: module import troubles

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I want to create a NestJS module I will host on my Verdaccio repository and reuse it into multiple projects, specially into guards. This module use the configService of the app where it is imported as a dependency. But when I import it into the app, I have dependency problems. I don't understand what's happening. Can someone help me to understand and solve this problem ?

First, the module files:
myModule.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MyService } from './myModule.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [MyService,ConfigService],
  exports: [MyService],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

myModule.service.ts

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class OIDCService {

    private readonly logger:Logger;

    constructor(@Inject("ConfigService") private readonly configService:ConfigService){
        this.logger = new Logger("MyService");
    }

   // ...
    myMethod(){
        const param = this.configService.get("param");
    }
}
```

Then, the app files:

app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigModule,ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import configValidator from './config/config.validator';
import { MyModule, myService } from 'myModule';
import configSchema from './config/config.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    validationSchema: configValidator,
    cache: true,
    load:[configSchema]
  }),ConfigModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [ConfigService,AppService,MyModule,MyService,ConfigModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

myGuard.ts

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Inject, Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { MyService } from 'myModule';

@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(@Inject() private readonly myService:MyService){}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    //...
    return (
      this.myService.myMethod()
      .then(//...)
    )
  }
}
```

This is the nest error : `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the OIDCModule (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigModule at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

Thanks !

Comment: you didn't shared the error message

Answer (score 1):

1. Modules **never** go in the `providers` array. **period**. They go in the `imports` array. Read that again. Good.
2. **Never** add a provider from a module that you are already importing to the current module's `providers` array. Every time you put a provider in the `providers` array, you tell Nest to create a new instance of that provider. In this case, your `MyMoudle` shouldn't have `ConfigService` in the `providers` array, it's already available because the `ConfigModule` is in the `imports` array **and** it `exports` the `ConfigService`.
3. Don't use a class's name string as the injection token (e.g. `@Inject('ConfigService')`) This worked back on Nest v7, but in v8 there was a change that made the class *reference* the injection token rather than the name alone.

   - If you are already using the class *type* as the type in the constructor **and** the class has a decorator at the class level (e.g. `@Injectable()`) **or** a parameter decorator in the constructor, then you don't need to `@Inject()` the class type **if** the class is a provided Nest provider (i.e. it's in a `providers` array). Typescript will emit the metadata for the parameters automatically and Nest will read that to know what to inject.

4. If you need to use `@Inject()`, don't do it without a parameter